# c# program to remove the given quantity in a collection of objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to subtract the qtyordered (8) from the list of items quantity. I have the given list below and

Pen1    5
Pen2    6
Pen3    7
Pen4    8

I am expecting the output:

Pen1    0
Pen2    3
Pen3    7
Pen4    8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int qtyordered = 8;
        var students = new List<Item>() { 
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen1", Qty=5},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen2", Qty=6},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen3", Qty=7},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen4", Qty=8},
            };
        // How to subtract 8 in the list quantity
//I am doing like below but it is not working as expected
var x = students.TakeWhile(c => (c.Qty -= qtyordered) >= 0);
        // expected output is 
        //Pen1 0  // 5-8
        //Pen2 3  //6-3
        //Pen3 7
        //Pen4 8
        
        
    }
    class Item{
        public string ItemName{get; set;}
        public int Qty{get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: So. what is the output now?  `-3, -2 ,-1, 0`? The problem is that the qtyordered stays 8. I wouldn't solve this in a linq statement, it's confusing (like you've noticed)  just create a simple for-loop.

Comment: The qtyordered will stay 8 but I have reduce the 8 in the list quantity. If the list item 1 is less than the qtyordered and I am not able to perform the operation.
I want the removed quantity in the same list, thats why I used linq and the result is wrong. no need to use linq. I am looking for best amicable solution

Comment: The output is pen 1 -13, rest all objects are same, It is not iterating to take away the qtyordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to keep track of the qtyordered and remove from the list at the same time, it would be tricky to just do it with Linq. Just use a simple For loop to go over the list of students and do some if checks. Once qtyordered hits zero break out of the loop.

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int qtyordered = 8;
        var students = new List<Item>() {
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen1", Qty=5},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen2", Qty=6},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen3", Qty=7},
                new Item(){ ItemName = "Pen4", Qty=8},
            };

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            if (qtyordered <= 0)
                break;

            if (student.Qty >= qtyordered)
            {
                student.Qty -= qtyordered;
                qtyordered = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                qtyordered -= student.Qty;
                student.Qty = 0;
            }
        }
        // output is 
        //Pen1 0  // 5-8
        //Pen2 3  //6-3
        //Pen3 7
        //Pen4 8


    }

    class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
}
```